# Как правильно реализовать переход на главную страницу после авторизации (MVC)?

Tags: php, mvc, solid

Есть `authorizationController`, который после успешной авторизации должен отправить пользователю главную страницу сайта. Но данные для этой страницы генерирует `mainPageController`. Насколько я понимаю принципы MVC, контроллеры не должны взаимодействовать между собой. Редирект на `mainPageController` выдаёт ошибку в браузере `ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT`. Дублирование кода с `mainPageController` в `authorizationController` нарушает принципы SOLID. Смотрела разные примеры реализаций MVC на PHP и поняла, что у каждого своё представление данной архитектуры. Я использую вот [этот (github repo)](https://github.com/Jontyy/PHP-Basic-MVC-Framework) подход к реализации MVC. Как всё-таки правильно в контроллере авторизации перенаправить пользователя на главную страницу?

Comment: верните в респонсе страницу с тегом редиректа `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0,URL=http://куда-то-там">`

Comment: @carcinogen75 работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Тот фрейм что вы используете, даже стыдно фреймворком-то назвать.

По поводу редиректа, так будет правильнее:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://куда-то-там');
exit;
```

Comment: Этот подход и выдаёт ошибку в браузере как небезопасный редирект. Вывод поводу фреймворка основывается на сравнение с такими, как Laravel, YII и т.д.? Или просто плохая реализация MVC?

Comment: @J.Huxley фреймворк это не просто реализация MVC, реализацию MVC в вашем случае это просто тупо 3 класса которые ничего не умеют. Фреймворк - это больше чем 3 класса. Можно сравнивать с гаражом, где есть стены, крыша, отопление и инструменты для работы, а в том что я увидел 4 столба по углам и трехногий стул.

Comment: этот репозиторий я фреймворком не называла. Сам фреймворк мне не нужен. У моего сайта должна быть небольшая функциональность + мне нужно сначала на чистом php понимать как всё должно быть устроено. Это у учебных целях, а не для продакшина. Ссылку на репозиторий скинула, чтобы пользователи форума понимали какакой я использую подход к MVC.